# How to unpublish content programmatically in Umbraco 7

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have been trying to unpublish a content programmatically in Umbraco 7 but it seems not to work as expected. Although the content was removed from the cache but the database record was never updated:

```
node.UnPublish();
umbraco.library.UnPublishSingleNode(node.Id);
```

After further investigation, I discovered that the method *UnPublishSingleNode* is obsolete:

```
[Obsolete("This method is no longer used, 
a document's cache will be removed automatically 
when the document is deleted or unpublished")]
public static void UnPublishSingleNode(int DocumentId);
```

The message did not suggest a new method :(

I need directions on how to unpublish a content programmatically.

**Umbraco version:** 7.3.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally got it to work through `Umbraco.Core.Services.IContentService`

**Usage:**

```
var contentServices = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService;
var content = contentServices.GetById(node.Id);
contentServices.UnPublish(content, 0);
```

I hope this helps others.